# Can i reference global variables in a composable function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm in the process of converting a project from Vue 2 options api to Vue 3 composition api.
In a options api component i have a variable called `componentData`, and from this component i'm calling a mixin. When i call the mixin, i can access all the component's variables from inside of the mixin, here is an example:

```
//myMixin.js
export default {
    methods: {
        data_changed() {
            //where componentData is declared in the component
            console.log(this.componentData)
            this.componentData = [1, 2, 3]
        },
    data() {
        return {
            someVar: null
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having a lot of troubles doing the same with the composition api. Instead of mixins, i have composables, so say i have a component where i'm declaring a variable:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { testData } from '../mixins/useData.js'

export default {
    setup() {
        const componentData = ref([])
        testData()
    }
}
```

And my composable **useData.js**:

```
export function testData() {
    console.log(componentData.value) //undefined
    componentData.value = [1, 2, 3] //will throw error
}
```

In this case, the composable will return `undefined`. How can i access the component's data without passing them as function parameters? Is that because in Vue3 composables are only supposed to return a value and they don't work the same as mixins? Is it possible to change the value of `componentData` from the composable?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the `ref` as an argument to `testData()`:

```js
// useData.js
export function testData(componentData) {
  componentData.value = [1, 2, 3] ✅
}
```

```js
// MyComponent.vue
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { testData } from '../mixins/useData.js'

export default {
    setup() {
        const componentData = ref([])
                     
        testData(componentData)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's referenced in the documentation you can! You can find the reference under [State Management](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api), here I quote:

> Although here we are using a single reactive object as a store, you can also share reactive state created using other Reactivity APIs such as ref() or computed(), or **even return global state from a Composable**:

And they use this code as example:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

// global state, created in module scope
const globalCount = ref(1)

export function useCount() {
  // local state, created per-component
  const localCount = ref(1)

  return {
    globalCount,
    localCount
  }
}
```